# How does one find annihilators for recurrence relations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I've recently taken an interest in the Method of Annihilators for solving recurrence relations.  However, I taught myself using nearly solely this [Power Point presentation](http://compbio.cs.uic.edu/~tanya/teaching/cs401/notes/kleinberg/02recurrences.pdf).  Thus, my knowledge is lacking in some ways.

My question is, **how does one "come up" with an annihilator?**  The presentation I saw showed how to prove/demonstrate an annihilator *works*, but now how to just pull one out of thin air.

**An example of what I'm talking about:**
How would I find an annihilator for $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}n\right)$?  I could just start guessing/writing out the sequence, and stumble upon the annihilator $(E^2-1)$  But, is there a *systematic* way to find this annihilator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick behind such terms is to consider them in the complex plane, I.e. $\sin \frac{\pi}{2} n = \frac{1}{2 \mathrm{i}} \left(\exp\left( \frac{\pi \mathrm{i}}{2}n\right) - \exp\left(-\frac{\pi\mathrm{i}}{2} n\right)\right)$, and this is just two $n$-th powers